# datetime in python and getting rid of 90 minutes "10" times

Tags: python, datetime

I am making a program which is supposed to take in a Wake up time that you want to wake up at, then it should minus 90 minutes (1 Hour and 30 Minutes)
10 times to get times you should go to sleep at, for example If i want to wake up at 11:30, then It would give me back 10:00 - 8:30 - 7:00 - 5:30 and so on.

Here below is the code I have and the last part is the one that isn't working with the for loop since I get an error "replace() takes no keyword arguments"

```
import datetime

#Gets the time you would like to wake up at

user_input = input("Write a time you'd like to wake up at like \"11:30\": ")

#Cuts the first piece off so if it were 11:30, this would get 11

first_user_time = user_input[0:2]
first_user_time = int(first_user_time)

#Cuts the second piece off so if it were 11:30, this would get 30

second_user_time = user_input[3:5]
second_user_time = int(second_user_time)

#Gets the current time today

this_time = datetime.datetime.today()

#Replaces the time of today to your set "Wake up time"

new_time = this_time.replace(hour=first_user_time ,minute=second_user_time).strftime("%H:%M")

#Prints out your wake up time

print("Wake Up Time:", new_time)

#This one is not working for me and I need help with this one
#It's supposed to get 10 different times where you could go to bed to wake up fresh at "11:30"

for i in range(10):
    the_hour = -1
    the_minute = -30

    sleep_time = new_time.replace(hour= the_hour, minute=the_minute).strftime("%H:%M")
    print("Your Sleep Times:", sleep_time)
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: @cricket_007  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Time.py", line 36, in <module>
    sleep_time = new_time.replace(hour= the_hour, minute=the_minute).strftime("%H:%M")
TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: You may [edit] your question with that information

Comment: check out `datetime.timedelta` instead of using `.replace()`. Then you do simple math `sleep_time  = new_time - datetime.timedelta(30)` or whatever you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html, which may be a solution to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a string after you `strftime`

```
new_time = this_time.replace(hour=first_user_time ,minute=second_user_time).strftime("%H:%M")
```

**String** `replace` doesn't take keyword arguments

```
for i in range(10):
    the_hour = -1
    the_minute = -30

    # Error here
    sleep_time = new_time.replace(hour= the_hour
```

So, remove the `strftime` until you actually want to display the value, and only then

Comment: Hmm Now i'm getting some different error because I try to hour=-1 and minute=-30 It's only allowed from 0...23, what can I do then?

Comment: @Kobbi I posted an answer that should resolve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, as cricket_007 noted, you can't pass keyword arguments to `.replace()` when it is a string. This works for the previous `.replace()` you did because that is a date object and has a method for replacing hours, minutes, etc. Same name, but really two different functions.

The other new issue you're getting is because it is trying to set the minute to -30 which is obviously not possible. You should use the `datetime.timedelta()` function to do this instead.

Try these updates:

Leave new_time as a datetime object so you can manipulate it properly

```
#Replaces the time of today to your set "Wake up time"

new_time = this_time.replace(hour=first_user_time ,minute=second_user_time)
```

Every time you want to display it, then call `strftime()`

```
#Prints out your wake up time

print("Wake Up Time:", new_time.strftime("%H:%M"))
```

In your loop, use `timedelta` to do the proper subtraction from a `datetime` object and again use `strftime()` when displaying to user.

```
for i in range(10):
    new_time = new_time - datetime.timedelta(hours=1, minutes=30)
    print("Your Sleep Times:", new_time.strftime("%H:%M"))
```